# How do I inject an HTTP-Request-specific object into my Unity supplied object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

For example, I store the "current user" in Session.  The business-layer object are being instantiated by Unity.  How do I make the business-layer object aware of the "current user"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should hide the "current user" behind an abstraction:

```
public interface ICurrentUser
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

This abstraction should be defined in the business layer and you need to create an ASP.NET specific implementation that you place in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/):

```
public class AspNetCurrentUser : ICurrentUser
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]; }
    }
}
```

Now your business-layer object can depend on the `ICurrentUser` interface, and in Unity you can register the implementation as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<ICurrentUser, AspNetCurrentUser>();
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using any static properties? Basically if I want to base it on the HttpRequestContext or on the Controller itself, how do I do that?

Comment: @CharlesPrakashDasari: Ask a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and post a link to that question as a comment to this answer.